# Count consecutive days during insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
Table Equipment   (EquipID,RentType)
Table EquipmentTimesheet  (EquipID (FK),Date)
```

The idea is upon inserting new rows in table "**EquipmentTimesheet**" I need to count if the previous 17 days are consecutive and then change the value of "**RentType**" Column in Table **"Equipments"**.

I have been trying several solutions with no way such as:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY GRP  ORDER BY Date) AS R, Date
FROM
(
SELECT 
    Date, DATEDIFF(Day, '1900-01-01' , Date)- ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Date ) AS GRP
FROM EquipmentTimeSheet WHERE EquipID = 29 ) A
```

This is what I get

[image: Results]

How can I modify the code above to achieve the goal I mentioned in my question?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What insert?  Do you want to create a trigger?  Do you just want to set the flag based on the data in the table?

Comment: What I need to do is to check before the insert if there are previous 17 rows of consecutive dates. creating a trigger or using any other way to update the data is not my issue. the real issue is to know if the previous 17 dates are consecutive . thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to "gaps and islands" problem and can be solved by below query:

```
declare @tbl table(dt date)
insert into @tbl values
('2020-02-01'),
('2020-02-02'),
('2020-02-03'),
('2020-02-05'),
('2020-02-06'),
('2020-02-10'),
('2020-02-12'),
('2020-02-13'),
('2020-02-18');

select min(dt) StartDate,
       count(*) ConsecutiveDays
from (
    select *, datepart(d, dt) - row_number() over (order by dt) grp
    from @tbl
) a group by grp
```

Comment: just chose MAX(dt) to fit my issue. This worked like a charm, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do it like this:

```
if (
 select count(*) from EquipmentTimesheet 
 where [Date] >= dateadd(d,-19,cast(getdate() as date)) 
 and EquipID = 29 
) = 19

update Equipment set RentType = 'whatever you need to update it to'
```

That will do it if the date you're inserting is today. Otherwise change the 3rd argument in the dateadd part

Comment: The select statement will always give you "1" whatever date you put